# Excel add ins | office-ui-fabric-react - DetailsList drag drop suddenly stopped working on Office 365 desktop excel add ins

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I have created Excel add-ins using office.js, react, office-ui-fabric-react.
In one of the requirement used DetailsList from office-ui-fabric-react for drag and drop the list items. [DetailsList - Drag drop list items](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/draganddrop) used this component.

DetailsList drag and drop items component was working fine until Feb 22, on both online and desktop office 365 version.
**Drag and Drop list items suddenly stopped working on Desktop Excel office 365 version.** I am able to drag and drop list items on online office 365 version on Edge and chrome browser.

**If I open application url on IE browser and then if I try to drag and drop the list items on desktop excel then drag and drop event is working.**

Can someone please help to understand what has been changed, or any office 365 update causing this issue.

Comment: A change in behavior on just one platform is often a bug. If you don't get an answer here in the next few days, try creating an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: sure Rick Kirkham, if we dont get answer will raise it. Thanks!